# Azure AD B2C registration mail takes over 5 minutes to arrive

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I've set up a new tenant with Azure AD B2C and when a new user is registering - the activation mail takes over 5 minutes to arrive.
This, of course, is unacceptable for a government public site.
Has anyone encountered this problem and know what can be changed ?

Comment: the reason may lay on 100s of places and only few of them are related to the AAD B2C send out logic. You have to better understand how the recipient email server works, inspect message headers, because each e-mail message has timestamps, and when you identify the issue is within AAD B2C - open a support ticket. My experience is that the e-mails usually arrive within 1 minute or less.

Comment: Have you tried against gmail.com?  or Outlook.com?